# How to debug virtual hosts in WAMP that don't seem to be working?

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to setup virtual host on my Windows machine. In my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file, I have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/blg"
    ServerName blg.com
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to `http://localhost`, I see all the folders under `c:/wamp/www`, so that looks fine. However, when I go to `http://blg.com`, I expect to see the files in `c:/wamp/www/blg`, but I don't. Instead, I am seeing exactly what localhost sees: the files in `c:/wamp/www`. What's wrong with my setup?

Comment: What apache version are you using? If it’s below 2.4, you might need to add a [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive.

Comment: 2.4.9 is the version I am using.

Comment: See this post on how to setup virtual hosts properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 1):

Apache has a fallback when a virtual host is not configured properly. It runs the FIRST Virtual Host it sees in your list of virtual hosts i.e. localhost in your case.

Your VHOST definitions are a bit lacking in content, and as you do not mention that you created an entry in the HOSTS file to match your `blg.com` domain that also could be one of your problems.

[Check this post out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011072/msvcr110-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer/26013219#26013219), as part of it it describes how to setup a Virtual host properly.